# Условие в обработчике события mouseenter

Tags: jquery

Как написать условие: если курсор над нужным элементом и нажата правая кнопка мыши.
Код:

```
 if (незнаю что здесь писать && e.button == "2"){ ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

Тогда лучше так пропиши:
 
`<button onmousedown="alert('Хелоу!')">нажми</button>`

Comment: мне именно условие нужно вида: if (незнаю что здесь писать && e.button == "2"){ ... }

Answer (score 0):

Пишите туда проверку e.target. Типа `e.target.id == 'id15'`.

Comment: чёт не понял

Comment: А что не поняли?

Answer (score 0):

```
elem.onmouseover = elemOver;
elem.onmouseout = elemOut;

function elemOver() {
    this.over = true; //мышка над нужным еллементом
}

function elemOut() {
   this.over = false; //уже нет
}
```

ну а дальше я думаю сами разберетесь :)

Comment: elem для чего нужен? и нет, нужно именно условие

Comment: елем это ваш елемент, ну ок мне тоже было бы интерестно увидеть решение в 1о условие, но что-то верится с трудом что таковое имеется